# how to access opencart logged in email to subfolder?

Tags: session, opencart2.x

I am trying set an email id in a session of opencart. But I am not able to do so.

How to set email id in session of opencart?
How can I access that email id in a subfolder?

I edited controller login as (line no 194)

```
$_SESSION['email']  = $this -> customer ->getEmail();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my solution. Added below code in login controller at line no 70.

```
$this->session->data['email']=$this->request->post['email'];
```